# Close Nav Menu On Click After Selecting Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I am trying to get my Javascript to close my nav menu bar after I choose a page from the dropdown menu. Currently, if I toggle the hamburger icon, it will show the menu, but when I click on one of the links in the menu bar, it takes my to that section, and the dropdown menu bar stays on screen. I would like for it to disappear after I tap one of the links in the menu bar.

HTML

```html
<nav>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><p class="logo-p"><i class = "fa-solid fa-code"></i><strong> HIBBERT</strong> DEVELOPMENT</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="hamburger">
        <div class="line1" style="width: 1.5rem;"></div>
        <div class="line2" style="width: 1rem;"></div>
        <div class="line3" style="width: 0.5rem;"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#offer">OFFER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://dylanhibbert.info">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");


hamburger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
   //Animate Links
    navLinks.classList.toggle("close");
    navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
    navLinks
    links.forEach(link => {
        link.classList.toggle("fade");
    });

    //Hamburger Animation
    hamburger.classList.toggle("toggle");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to add a click event listener for each of your links while you're toggling the fade class.

```
links.forEach(link => {
   link.classList.toggle("fade");
   link.addEventListener("click", () => {
     hamburger.classList.toggle("toggle");
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @villecoder. However, the issue persists after adding this to the JavaScript.

Comment: @dylanhibbert1 Could you add your css to your question, please? That might help track down the issue. Or at least give me something I can try in a sandbox.